# Playwright on google colab : Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x29000020c5a0

Tags: python, exception, async-await, python-asyncio, playwright

I was trying to run playwright on google colab but getting an error

##### Installed playwright and chromium

```
!pip install playwright 
!playwright install
```

##### To run run async stuff in a notebook

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

##### My Code

```
import time
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page(storage_state='auth.json')
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com')
        time.sleep(6)
        html = await page.content()

        time.sleep(5)

        # await browser.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

which gives me following error

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/futures.py in result(self)
    179         self.__log_traceback = False
    180         if self._exception is not None:
--> 181             raise self._exception
    182         return self._result
    183 

Error: Browser closed.
==================== Browser output: ====================
<launching> /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1015/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-IAbW15 --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
<launched> pid=656
[pid=656][err] src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x29000020c5a0 
=========================== logs ===========================
<launching> /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1015/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-IAbW15 --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
<launched> pid=656
[pid=656][err] src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x29000020c5a0
```

Comment: `headless=False` - does Google Colab runs with a GUI? Change that to True and try again

Comment: I tried with `headless=True` but it did not work, same error `[pid=258][err] src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x19180020c5a0 `

Comment: To run headed on Google Colab: `!apt install xvfb; pip install pyvirtualdisplay` and `import pyvirtualdisplay; display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(); display.start()`, credits goes to [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13bQO6G_hzE1teX35a3NZ4T5K-ICFFdB5?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 3):

When I try to run the chromium browser that downloaded by playwright using this command

```
!/root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1033/chrome-linux/chrome
```

It gives this error

```
src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x18400020c5a0
```

It means the problem is somehow related to the browser downloaded by playwright.
We can use a different browser.

First, install chromium.

```
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Set executable_path and user_data_dir with launch_persistent_context in your code.

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(
            executable_path="/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
            user_data_dir="/content/random-user"
        )
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("https://google.com")
        title = await page.title()
        print(f"Title: {title}")
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

I know this is not the right solution but it works.

#### Update

Since google colab updated to ubuntu 20.04 installing chromium-browser requires snap and I couldn't install chromium with snap.

But [in this github comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4991#issuecomment-1037769825) someone had already found the real problem(it is about root privilege).

If we follow the same steps and for testing save the code below into a file named test_playwright.py on google colab

```py
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("https://google.com")
        title = await page.title()
        print(f"Title: {title}")
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Run it with sudo:

```
!sudo python test_playwright.py
```

It works.

Comment: Thanks. This makes playwright to work on colab. so this is a right solution